# Simple PHP Encryption Program

Tags: php

I'm not really sure why this simple PHP script is not working,

My browser won't load the page. I'm thinking that its a flaw in the logic rather than syntax, but perhaps someone here would be kind enough to point out what/why I am going wrong.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Encryption Program</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?PHP
    $ConvertedLetter ="";
    $SecretMessage= "Kiss My Shiny Metal...";
    $MessageLength = strlen($SecretMessage);
    $Counter = 0;
    For($Counter;$MessageLength;$Counter++){
        $LetterToEncrypt = substr($SecretMessage,$Counter,1);
        $AsciiNumber = ord($LetterToEncrypt) + 3;
        $ConvertedLetter = $ConvertedLetter + Chr($AsciiNumber);
    }
    echo $ConvertedLetter;
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your loop will run infinite times ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php
//^^^ good practice in lowercase

    $ConvertedLetter ="";
    $SecretMessage= "Kiss My Shiny Metal...";
    $MessageLength = strlen($SecretMessage);

    for($Counter = 0; $Counter < $MessageLength; $Counter++) {
  //^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^ You need a condition for a for loop
  //|   | Initialize the variable
  //| good practice control structure in lowercase

        $LetterToEncrypt = $SecretMessage[$Counter];
                         //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ You can access a string like an array
        $AsciiNumber = ord($LetterToEncrypt) + 3;
        $ConvertedLetter .= chr($AsciiNumber);
                       //^^ ^^^ wrote the function name in the same case as it is defined
                       //| Append the string
    }

    echo $ConvertedLetter;

?>
```

Output:

```
Nlvv#P|#Vklq|#Phwdo111
```

For more information see:

- [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)
- [access single character from a string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr)
- [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

**Side Notes:**

Add [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s) only while staging, NOT in production:

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Also before you make the mistake:

[Variables are case-sensitive](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) not (But it's still good practice to write them in the same case as they are defined)!

And a few references which may help you in the future to solve such problems yourself or at least get an answer faster (Hover over it!vvv)!

> [google](https://www.google.com) Google is your best friend! (He will never lie to you, trust me :D)
>  [php manual](http://php.net/) Always a good start to search for something
>  [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) This will help you to get an answer fast!

Comment: Many thanks for your patience.Your answer has helped me to identify where I am going wrong. I understand that it looks like I posted this without prior research, but this was not the case. When your new to the programming, the simplest things can trip you up and it can take forever to teach yourself the basics.

Comment: @RickTicky You're welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: I updated my answer with a few references at the bottom)

Comment: Huge apologies. I up-voted your answer but did not hit the tick. Have done so now!